# Не всегда есть видео Vitamio

Tags: android, videoview

Использую Vitamio в своем проекте. Код приводить не стану, так как он взят из примера и рабочий. Инициализацию провожу, в манифест добавил и его инит активити и интернет пермишн.

Тестировал и выявил на:

-Эмулятор андроид 4.0.3-5.1
-Телефон с подключением по wifi
-Другой телефон с подключением к 3g

Суть в том что иногда вместо видео+звук воспроизводится только звук. Вместо видео- черный экран.

Перезапуск приложения рандомно приводит к таким же результатам- либо просто звук, либо все нормально. Иногда несколько перезапусков подряд все хорошо, а иногда ровным счетом наоборот.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может крыться проблема и по возможности как исправить.

Спасибо.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25813370/4829111

Comment: На самом деле это совсем другой подход, не подходит мне для проекта( есть еще идеи? я буду очень благодарен за помощь!